# DRF Django: Serializer: HOw to get list of other properties in many to many relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    something = models.TextField()
    bars = models.ManyToMany("app.Bar")

class Bar(models.Model):
    example = models.TextField()

class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ["example"]


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    testing = BarSerializer(many=True,source=bars,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = "__all__"


{
  "something": "Testing",
  "testing": [
    {
      "example": "Something else"
    }
    {
      "example": "Something else2"
    }
  ],
  "bars":[
        "Something else",
        "Something else2",
    ]

}
```

What I see is

```
  "testing": [
    {
      "example": "Something else"
    }
    {
      "example": "Something else2"
    }
  ],
```

What i want is

```
  "testing": [
      "Something else",
      "Something else2"
  ],
```

Comment: Where is `children` coming from? Also what you want is not a valid json/dict

Comment: sorry corrected and updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [**`SlugRelatedField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to simulate this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    testing = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='example',
        source='bars'
    )
```